# Use multiple domains in gettext in a PHP application

Tags: php, gettext

By domain I mean the gettext domain. I have this code

```
$domain = "default";
$locale = 'en_US';
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain($domain, 'my_path'); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');    
textdomain($domain);
```

So It will use the my_path/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/default.po

But I want to use more than 1 file so I can <s>override</s> overwrite the value in default.po
with another po file like admin.po, blog.po, etc

Comment: What do you mean by `override`? You want to define the same `msgid` in two .po files?

Comment: I guess he always want to load default.mo, but also want to load page-specific mo files. That's completely unnecessary in my opinion, and will make the whole app more complex for no real gain. Also you won't be able to reuse strings across different po files. For example if you have a string "cancel" in "admin.po", that you later also need in "blog.po", you'll have to copy them, or move them to default.po, etc. So complicated...

Comment: I don't understand what the *domain* means and why we need domain. Could you give some explanations or  related links?

Answer (score 20):

First define *all* your domains something like this:

```
bindtextdomain('domain1', DIR_LOCALE);
bindtextdomain('domain2', DIR_LOCALE);
bindtextdomain('domain3', DIR_LOCALE);
textdomain('domain1'); // set default domain for _() function
```

Now if you want to grab strings from a different domain, you'd use either `dgettext()` or `dcgettext()` (if not from `LC_MESSAGES`) to retrieve just a single string from a different, specified domain. Example:

```
echo dgettext('domain2', "msgid");
```

Comment: Is there need defined directory structure for DIR_LOCALE2 like "loc2/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/default.po"
"loc3/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/default.po"

Comment: How can I load multiple mo files together if each has different msgid. Is each gettext provide support for this?

Comment: You must use function first param on dgettext function. I will post my use case later, but @DanMan this is by far the better answer.